# Is there any way to download the AUTOMATED captions of a youtube video through the API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am able to get captions from the videos that have manually entered captions, but am unable to get captions from videos with only automated captions.

To put it another way, I am able to get the caption listings of any video, but the download endpoint only works when the caption's **snippet.trackKind** is not "ASR"

I have the authorization with the scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

Is there any way to solve this? It seems like a silly restriction.

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions#snippet.trackKind),`ASR` is a valid value for `snippet.trackKind` property. However, based from this [thread](https://github.com/medialab/artoo/issues/164), the YouTube API is only available to channel owners. You may consider using [`artoo.js`](https://github.com/medialab/artoo) which is a chrome extension that would download the received subtitles. Note however that subtitles come in a strange `xml` format and would probably need a conversion.

Comment: @abielita thanks for the reply, 
I am able to download subtitles for for snippets that aren't ASR, so it isn't that the api is only available to channel owners. It may be that only automatic subtitle downloading is available to channel owners, but I do not know. It seems a weird restriction to only be able to download non-automatic subtitles, which is why I asked.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?